# `Solve` hangs on linear combination of two quadratic formulas

Tags: equation-solving

I have two solutions to a quadratic equation, an upper solution (hi) and lower solution (lo):

$$
    \frac
      {2c}
      {-b_{\mathrm{lo}} - \sqrt{b_{\mathrm{lo}}^{2} - 4a_{\mathrm{lo}}c}}
    \quad
    \mathrm{and}
    \quad
    \frac
      {2c}
      {-b_{\mathrm{hi}} - \sqrt{b_{\mathrm{hi}}^{2} - 4a_{\mathrm{hi}}c}}
$$

I chose the above forms since I am only interested in one solution, have $b>0$, and sometimes expect $a=0$.

Linearly interpolating between the two solutions I have

$$
    z =
    (1-r)
    \frac
      {2c}
      {-b_{\mathrm{lo}} - \sqrt{b_{\mathrm{lo}}^{2} - 4a_{\mathrm{lo}}c}}
    +
    r
    \frac
      {2c}
      {-b_{\mathrm{hi}} - \sqrt{b_{\mathrm{hi}}^{2} - 4a_{\mathrm{hi}}c}}
$$

and am interested in solving this equation for $c$. Based on a [related question on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4684550/475643), I think this should come out to a quadratic equation in $c$. The following computation

```
Solve[z == (1 - r) (
    2 c)/(-Subscript[b, lo] - Sqrt[
     Subscript[b, lo]^2 - 4  Subscript[a, lo] c]) + 
   r (2 c)/(-Subscript[b, hi] - Sqrt[
     Subscript[b, hi]^2 - 4  Subscript[a, hi] c]), c, Reals]
```

hangs. I am on Wolfram Mathematica 13.1.0.0 on MacOS 13.3.1.

Comment: Try without specifying the domain (`Reals`) of solutions.

Comment: Maybe this helps. `GroebnerBasis[
  z - (1 - r) (2 c)/(-b[lo] - Sqrt[b[lo]^2 - 4 a[lo] c]) + 
   r (2 c)/(-b[hi] - Sqrt[b[hi]^2 - 4 a[hi] c]), c][[1]]

c + z^2 a[hi] - z b[hi]`

Comment: @E.Chan-López That seemed to work, thanks! It gave me two solutions which are fairly long though so I think I'll so this by hand to get it in terms of variables that will be easier to code up.

Comment: @segfault Glad to help!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.